# Huge JSON while saving and returning entity using Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to save my entities to database. For simple example I have two entities:

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Wheel> wheelList;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String name, List<Wheel> wheelList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wheelList = wheelList;
    }
```

and Wheel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wheel")
public class Wheel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private int size;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Car car;

    public Wheel() {
    }

    public Wheel(int size, Car car) {
        this.size = size;
        this.car = car;
    }
```

I am using Spring Framework (MVC) to create REST client, from which I return JSON. 
And now: I created simple @Repository and @Service.

I wanted to try if saving works, so I created simple Car object with its wheel list etc. and then, in @Service layer I have persisted it and returned car object into the controller.

Finally, when i run the url from the controller, I recieve HUGE json, because every Car object has wheel list, and then, every wheel has its car, which again has list, and in list are wheels which has cars and so on.. thats why my JSON is so big.

```
{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":{"id":1,"name":"SomeName","wheelList":[{"id":1,"size":1,"car":...........
```

What do i do wrong? How should i solve this problem?

Rest of the code if you need it:(made just for tests, I know about not-well-coded-style here)
Repository:

```
@Repository
public class TestImpl {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Car saveCar(Car car){
        entityManager.persist(car);
        return car;
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private TestImpl test;

    public Car save(){
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setName("SomeName");
        List<Wheel> list = new ArrayList<Wheel>();
        list.add(new Wheel(1, car));
        car.setWheelList(list);
        test.saveCar(car);
        return car;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/los")
    @ResponseBody
    public Car los(){
        return testService.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the relations are all wrong. Why does a `Wheel` need a `Car` property? Cars have wheels, wheels don't have cars.

Comment: Actually main relations are between Users and Reports. Every User has reportlist, and every Report has its owner(reporter). Cars and Wheels are made just for tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to either `wheelList` field in your `Car` object or to `car` field in your `Wheel` object. This will stop JSON serializer from showing those fields in the resulting document and from recursively including the field.

Comment: yes but when I add @JsonIgnore to wheelList property, then my JSON is like this:{"id":1,"name":"SomeName"}. So it lacks list property.

Comment: @azalut add the property to the `car` field in the `Wheel` object so it shows the car along with all the wheels but not going back to car

Comment: perfect! thanks for your help. btw I would like to ask, do you maybe have some useful annotation list with hibernate/json/spring? somethimes there are some that we need, but we dont know about them, like now

Comment: @azalut no, sorry. Googling your question is probably the best way to find out about this kind of stuff

Comment: I was working whole day, and I thought now, that my JSON doesnt have the user from Wheel object. Its not so big problem, but what should I do when client send json TO my controller to save it? how should then the JSON look like? it will be recursed, or Car field will be empty